# Generating 3D coordinates error

Tags: docking, 3d-structure

I have been trying to convert a multi entry sdf file to pdb using openbabel. Everytime I check the Generate 3D coordinates box I end up with .ENT files instead of .PDB files. What am I doing wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: Voting to close, lacks details and reproducibility.

Answer (score 2):

An ent file is a pdb file. Just change the extension. [PDBe](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/pdbe/node/1) for example provides their PDB files as such.

Comment: ok. I tried opening the .ent file with Autodock but I kept getting the error, .ent file is an unrecognized format. How can I simultaneously change the extension for 50,000 ent files to pdb without having to do it manually for each one individually. 

Thank you,
Dr. Hussain.

Comment: In your file manager, select all and rename